# best method for saving data from multiple check boxes in asp master page to sqlserver

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, database-design

what is the best way to save data from multiple checkboxes ?? if i have 50 , 60 checkboxes

Is it reasonable to set up a column of 50 or 60 checkboxes  for ٍsaving value for each question separately ?
and presumably there are questions that have not responded what should i do ??

```
<div class="form-group">    
                             <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Moderate
                                </label>

                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" class="form-control"  />
                            </div>  

                               <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Heavy
                                </label>

                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" class="form-control"  />
                            </div> 


                         <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                               Y
                                </label>

                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4"runat="server" class="form-control"  />
                            </div> 
                             <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                              N
                                </label>

                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" class="form-control"  />
                            </div> 

and so on ...
```

Comment: There are several possible ways. But how are these "questions" or checkboxes interrelated? Are they configuration settings? 50 different true and false questions? Could there be more questions added later? I would say that the answers to these questions would relate directly to the approach you would use in modeling your data.

P.S. Consider using a CheckBoxList, if at all possible, rather than repeat the markup for each checkbox.

Comment: thank you ..

some of questions: yes/No Q  and some of it : multiple-choice

it is possible to  be more questions added later

Comment: It seems like you will need a combination of CheckBoxes/CheckBoxLists and RadioButtonLists. Ideally you will want to have something dynamic to cleanly generate your questions.  rot26 did touch upon one possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would set up my checkboxes with either a CheckBoxList as thesentiment said, or if you need more control over layout, you could use your same markup inside something like a Repeater that you could bind to a list of questions/answers stored in the database. I would avoid saving each answer separately, as you don't want to make a separate call to the database for each question, but rather you should make one call in which you pass back all your answers at once. Basically on the save, you loop through the CheckBoxList or Repeater Items (they should be collections in the control itself) and get the value of the checked answer.

It is hard to say what your save methodology should be without knowing your db design. I think what I'd try to do is pass back a QuestionID and an AnswerID per question to the database, or something akin to that. There are a lot of fun methods to accomplish this. A relatively easy one is to form xml in your save loop and pass this to SQL Server, and then parse this xml into a CTE using a custom table-valued function. I'm a little rusty on this one, but I believe you could also set up a user-defined table type in SQL Server with the QuestionID and AnswerID as the columns. Then in the save loop, you basically create a table to pass along. I believe you can do this with a DataSet. Again, I'm not as familiar with that way. Whatever method you choose, the main idea is to have one table/list of records or key-value pairs to save.

In SQL Server, then you just need to create an Update statement from this table or CTE.

If you need to clear out answers that have no selection, there are also several ways to do this. If you only pass back QuestionIDs that have an answer, you can use a not exists where clause to set the AnswerID to null or delete it altogether where that QuestionID is in the db table for that user but not in your passed in table or CTE. Or in your save loop, you could set the AnswerID to 0 or -1 or something like that when there's no selection for a quesiton, and in your Update use a Case statement to set the AnswerID to null when that value is present.

You can adjust this accordingly for your own setup, but I hope that helps get you started!

Comment: thank you your answer is useful but i want to know what is the best method to customize table size in sql server db  i didn't create the database yet

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "customize table size"? Do you mean the data types of the columns in the table? rot26 pretty much summarized what you can do above.

Comment: @rot26, yes, you are on point with the user-defined table type. I would say the best approach is to use a DataTable on the .NET side to pass a set of values to a stored procedure that updates the data. The stored procedure would have a parameter whose data type is the user-defined table type. XML would work too, but I'm not too familiar with that. It might not be as efficient as passing in the data directly due to the parsing required, but it would probably suffice as a start.